# Symbolic links - move files

Tags: files

How can I change symbolic links for targeted files? (move targeted files to place where are linked from)

I hope I'm clear.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean automatically?

Comment: Just remove the symlink from the location, and recreate it.

Comment: I can write a script to make it automatic, but is there any command? I need reverse of ln - change link to target by copying target to symlink file.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not in `man ln`, then `ln` definitely cannot do it.

But this should:

```
find /path/to/dir -type l -exec sh -c 'cp --remove-destination "$(readlink "{}")" "{}"' \;
```

The quotes are to take care of file names with spaces in them.

The `-exec` calling into `sh` is to evaluate `$(readlink ...)` for each file.

Comment: 7zipping the folder made all work for me. :D